# Other than Linq to SQL does anything else consume INotifyPropertyChanging?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

Having never used `INotifyPropertyChanging` i was wondering if anything other than Linq to SQL uses it?

And if Linq to SQL is the only user why does `INotifyPropertyChanging` exist in System.ComponentModel?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanging.aspx

Comment: Well since LINQ to SQL is part of the .NET framework, then anything it depends on would need to be there too... or is the question, why does it live outside the LINQ to SQL assemblies/namespaces?

Comment: Rex. good point. question updated

Comment: `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject` is another implementor.  As is `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>`, `System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase`, etc.

Comment: Kirk. I am looking for consumers of the interface not implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Reflector ;) INotifyPropertyChanging is used in Linq to SQL and its third party analogs (like Devart.Data.Linq) to optimize entity change tracking (delaying entity snapshot till first change).

Basically, if you load X objects, the owning DataContext will create X copies of those objects (snapshots), if they don't implement INotifyPropertyChanging.

With implemented INotifyPropertyChanging, only X PropertyChangingEventHandlers will be created. But as soon, as first change comes, DataContext starts cloning.

So, to implement INotifyPropertyChanging makes sense only then, when your classes are data entities in DataContext (Linq to Sql), loaded in massive amounts and mostly for read operation.

I would also like to see optional support of INotifyPropertyChanging in your Weaver project ;)

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment and it seems like a logical progression. But how often have you wanted to be notified before a property is changing? Can you give me a scenario? Happy to have you raise it as a feature request http://code.google.com/p/notifypropertyweaver/issues/list and have a discussion there